# Get the caret position of a Firefox window

Tags: vba, windows, firefox, caret, user32

The code below will correctly get the caret position on screen of a notepad window.  But when run for Firefox it returns all zeros?

I’m I do doing something wrong?   Or does Firefox just self-draw the caret onscreen outside of the Windows OS?  If the later, is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Thanks

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetGUIThreadInfo Lib "user32" (ByVal dwthreadid As Long, lpguithreadinfo As GUITHREADINFO) As Long

    Private Type RECT
        Left As Long
        Top As Long
        Right As Long
        Bottom As Long
    End Type
    Private Type GUITHREADINFO
        cbSize As Long
        flags As Long
        hwndActive As Long
        hwndFocus As Long
        hwndCapture As Long
        hwndMenuOwner As Long
        hwndMoveSize As Long
        hwndCaret As Long
        rcCaret As RECT
    End Type

    Private Function GetCaretPosition() As GUITHREADINFO
        Dim pThreadId As Long
        Dim guiInfo As GUITHREADINFO
        pThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), &H0)
        guiInfo.cbSize = LenB(guiInfo)
        GetGUIThreadInfo pThreadId, guiInfo
        GetCaretPosition = guiInfo
    End Function

    Private Sub Test()

        Dim guiInfo As GUITHREADINFO
        'Works on notepad
        AppActivate "Notepad"
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        guiInfo = GetCaretPosition()
        Debug.Print guiInfo.flags, guiInfo.hwndFocus, guiInfo.hwndCaret, guiInfo.rcCaret.Left, guiInfo.rcCaret.Top, guiInfo.rcCaret.Right, guiInfo.rcCaret.Bottom
        'Returns:  1             5119032       5119032       5             0             6             22
   
        'Doesn't work on Firefox
        AppActivate "Firefox"
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        guiInfo = GetCaretPosition()
        Debug.Print guiInfo.flags, guiInfo.hwndFocus, guiInfo.hwndCaret, guiInfo.rcCaret.Left, guiInfo.rcCaret.Top, guiInfo.rcCaret.Right, guiInfo.rcCaret.Bottom
        'Returns:   0             5444838       0             0             0             0             0

End Sub
```

Comment: Correct, I don't believe Firefox uses `USER32` carets at all.

Comment: @Dai - that's a shame.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution... WARNING it is using a intrusive method of SendKeys and clipboard access to test if the caret active is on the window.  I have got it to tidy up as it goes, but still could have undesired affects depending on the context in which it's used.

It doesn't return the caret position; just a true/false indicator whether or not the window as can active caret.

It's usueful if trying to identify when an opened window has keyboard focus and is ready for further SendKeys; just setup to run the check in a loop until true or suitable timeout has passed

```
Option Explicit
 
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
 
Private Sub test2()
   
    AppActivate "Notepad"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Debug.Print WindowHasKeyboardFocus(GetForegroundWindow())
    'Returns True
   
    AppActivate "Firefox"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Debug.Print WindowHasKeyboardFocus(GetForegroundWindow())
    'Returns True
 
End Sub
 
Private Function WindowHasKeyboardFocus(hwnd As Long) As Boolean
   
    Dim WSH As Object
    Dim UserClipboard As String
   
    Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   
    'Copy of user's clipboard for later restore
    UserClipboard = GetClipboard()
    SetClipboard ""
 
    'Send keys to prove it has keyboard focus
    WindowHasKeyboardFocus = False
    If SetForegroundWindow(hwnd) <> 0 Then
        WSH.SendKeys "a+{LEFT}^x" 'Type "a", then select it and cut it to clipboard
        Sleep 200
        WindowHasKeyboardFocus = GetClipboard() = "a"
    End If
   
    'Restore User's clipboard
    SetClipboard UserClipboard
   
    Set WSH = Nothing
 
End Function
 
Private Sub Sleep(Milliseconds As Long)
    Dim WaitTimer As Double
    WaitTimer = Timer + Milliseconds / 1000
    While Timer < WaitTimer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
 
Private Function GetClipboard() As String
   
    Dim X As Long
    Dim CB As Object
    Set CB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
   
    'Get data from Clipboard (sometimes fails so done on loop)
    On Error Resume Next
    For X = 1 To 100
        CB.GetFromClipboard
        GetClipboard = CB.GetText
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 0: Exit For
            Case -2147221040: Err.Clear 'Try Again (DataObject:GetText OpenClipboard Failed)
            Case Else: Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
        End Select
    Next
    
    'Pass back any error that occured
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
    End If
   
    Set CB = Nothing
 
End Function
 
Private Function SetClipboard(Value As String)
   
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Timeout As Single
    Dim CB As Object
    Set CB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
   
    'Prone to errors
    On Error Resume Next
   
    'Put data into Clipboard (sometimes fails so done on loop)
    CB.SetText Value
    For X = 1 To 100
        CB.PutInClipboard
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 0: Exit For
            Case -2147221040: Err.Clear 'Try Again (DataObject:PutInClipboard OpenClipboard Failed)
            Case Else: Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
        End Select
    Next
   
    'Pass back any error that occured
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
    End If
   
    Set CB = Nothing

End Function
```